# How to tell NSwag C# Client generator to use our DTOs instead of generating new ones?

Tags: c#, dto, nswag

We currently have over 100 DTOs already well-designed in a separate assembly and span multiple namespaces. How can we instruct the NSwag C# client generator to utilize our existing DTO library instead of generating its own DTOs?

Answer (score 3):

I found it:

```
{
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToCSharpClient": {
      "generateDtoTypes": false,
      "additionalNamespaceUsages": [
        "Your.DTOTypes.Namespace"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```